# Laravel vue js mixins not getting function response

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.8 with vue js. I have created a generalized function for post/get requests. The problem is, i am not getting the mixins function response. Here is my code :

**TestComponent.vue**

```
import GeneralMixin from '../mixins.js';
export default {
    mixins: [ GeneralMixin ],
    methods:{
        login: function (e) {
            let response;
            response = this.testMixin();
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
}
```

**mixin.js**

```
export default {
    methods: {
        testMixin: function () {
            url = '/test';
            axios.post(url).then(function(response, status, request) {  
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The console result is `undefined`

I am not getting response of function `testMixin()` . Can anyone help please

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: Yes updating the question!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the response from the mixin then you're going to need to wrap that axios request in a promise:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.post(url).then(function(response, status, request) {  
     return resolve(response)
  })
})
```

And if you want the result of that from another function:

```
login: function (e) {
  this.textMixin().then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
  })
}
```

But really it's an anti pattern to return only the response from the promise. The way you've created this mixin serves as a psuedo-API for you to consume internally, so instead just return the axios request:

```
return axios.post(url)
```

Now you can handle this yourself:

```
login: function(e) {
    this.testMixin().then((response) => {
       console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error.response.data)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the promise, Something like below

In you mixin

```
return axios.post(url);
```

And now in component use it like below.

```
this.testMixin().then((response) => {
       console.log(response)
    }).catch((error) => {
       console.log(error.response.data)
    })
```